# Javascript - Text on Image

Tags: javascript

Using appendChild I am putting an Image into a div, but what I want to do is write the Name and LightLevel onto that Image (or over it).

How do I approach this?

I am not entirely sure, I was wondering if I could edit the image from the link after I put it into the document?

```
const { Client } = require('destiny2');
const client = new Client('apiKey');

window.memberName = function(){
   var pName = document.getElementById("pageheader");
   var pId = document.getElementById('memberId');
   var pLl = document.getElementById('LightLevel');
   var pLl2 = document.getElementById('LightLevel2');
   var pLl3 = document.getElementById('LightLevel3');
   var gT = document.getElementById('Guardian');
   var gT2 = document.getElementById('Guardian2');
   var gT3 = document.getElementById('Guardian3');
   var divI = document.getElementById('character1img');
   var name = document.getElementById('search').value;

client.getProfile(name, '4')
   .then(data => console.log(data));

client.getProfile(name, '4').then(data => {
    pName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${data.profile.displayName}`));

// Character 1
   // Emblem Image
       var elem = document.createElement("img");
       elem.src = `http://bungie.net${data.characters[0].embemBackground}`;
       var image = 
       document.getElementById('character1img').appendChild(elem);
   // Light Level
       pLl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`♦ 
      ${data.characters[0].light}`));
// Guardian Type
    if (`${data.characters[0].classHash}` == 671679327) {
        gT.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hunter'));

    } else if (`${data.characters[0].classHash}` == 2271682572){
        gT.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Warlock'));

    } else {
        gT.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Titan'));
    }

   });
}
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or screenshot for the page demo?

Comment: This is what the page looks like after the function.
https://i.imgur.com/ZKFa8Bl.png

jsfiddle wouldn't work as I am using NPM.

Comment: are you looking for css styling like this? https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Comment: I tried that but it just puts the LightLevel on top of the image, not on the image.

Comment: the code in the link places text on the image, did you want it above, as in before, the image?

Comment: @AODSaenai you are asking a html/css styling question. If you copy the whole html output code from you page someone will be able to help you out.